# How to support backwards-compatible serialization when refactoring a class into an interface in Java?

Tags: java, serialization, backwards-compatibility

Unfortunately, the situation in the question title has already happened several years in the past.

I have an `Id` interface which extends `Serializable` and contains getters for a name and id number.  There is a matching `IdImpl` class which implements the interface.  However, at some point in the past, `Id` *was* the class.  There is also a serializable container object which has member fields of type `Id`.  These container objects have been being serialized to a database for several years, so there are versions of the container object out there containing both types of `Id`s.  When attempting to deserialize the old objects, we get an `InvalidClassException`.  How can I deserialize the old container objects which contain the old `Id` concrete class instances?

Full disclosure: a couple of other changes to the `Id` interface have been made over the years, but I thought they looked like [compatible changes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html#6678) (added a field to `IdImpl` and a getter to `Id` for "String idType"; generified `Comparable`).  Could one of these changes be causing the problem too?

The classes look something like this:

```
// current Id interface
public interface Id extends Serializable, Comparable<Id> {
    String getName();
    int getIdNumber();
}

// current Id implementation
public class IdImpl implements Id {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 10329865109284L;
    private String name;
    private int idNumber;
    IdImpl(String name, int idNumber) { this.name = name; this.idNumber = idNumber; }
    @Override public String getName() { return name; }
    @Override public int getIdNumber() { return idNumber; }
    @Override public int compareTo(Id id) { /* some code here */ }
}

// the container object
public ContainerForm implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3294779665912049275L;
    private String someField;
    private Id user;
    private String someOtherField;
    // getters and setters
}

// this is what the _old_ Id concrete class looked like
// (from source control history; not in current project)
public class Id implements Serializable, Comparable {
    // never had a serialVersionUID
    private String name;
    private int idNumber;
    Id(String name, int idNumber) { this.name = name; this.idNumber = idNumber; }
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public int getIdNumber() { return idNumber; }
    public int compareTo(Object id) { /* some code here */ }
}
```

The exception we get when trying to deserialize container objects is:

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: mypkg.people.Id; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -6494896316839337071, local class serialVersionUID = -869017349143998644
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:562)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1583)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1732)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
    at mypkg.forms.FormFactory.getForm(FormFactory.java:3115)
    ... 34 more
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a general rule, *not* using serialVersionUID and turning a class into an interface is a very difficult transition to support.

In this specific instance, i *believe* you could support the old `Id` implementation by:

- create a class (call it `OldId`) which has the old serialVersionUID and old implementation of `Id` (it should implement `Id`).
- create a custom subclass of ObjectInputStream and override the `readClassDescriptor()` method.  call the parent readClassDescriptor and

  - if the returned ObjectStreamClass has the `Id` class name and the old serialVersionUID, return the ObjectStreamClass for the new `OldId` class
  - otherwise return the given descriptor

Comment: Thanks for leading me to the solution.  I created an `OldId` class, but overriding `resolveClass` didn't work, because then `ObjectInputStream` complained the class name didn't match what was declared in the stream.  I ended up [overriding `readClassDescriptor` to return a different `ObjectStreamClass`](http://www.norwinter.com/2009/08/20/refactor-serializable-java-class/) instead.